# Problem using OrderBy with the entity framework and ObjectContext.CreateQuery(T)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository, sql-order-by

I'm having troubles using this method:

```
public ObjectQuery<E> DoQuery(string columnName, int maximumRows, int startRowIndex)
{
    var result = (ObjectQuery<E>)_ctx.CreateQuery<E>
    ("[" + typeof(E).Name + "]").OrderBy(/*???*/).Skip<E>(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows);

    return result;
}
```

I'm not sure what needs to go in the `OrderBy` section. I've tried leaving out `.OrderBy` but it ends up giving me an error saying that it needs to be ordered so that I can take a certain amount of rows.

I want to order by the ID field. In one case I have the entity name as Row, the ID of this entity is named `RowID`.

Does anyone know how I could order by the ID field?

**Note:** This is a generic repository using the entity framework. The columnName passed in is the column I would like to order by, but it will probably only be the name of the ID field.

Answer (score 4):

You just do:

```
.OrderBy("it.Id")
```

...presuming your ID field is called "Id". In query builder, the "it" means the entity. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716784.aspx#_QueryBuilder) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

When I created my repository, I assumed that every EntityObject has ID property. Then I Created repository:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : EntityObject, IBasicEntityInfo
```

IBasicEntityInfo:

```
public interface IBasicEntityInfo
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
OrderBy(a => a.ID)
```

Automatically generated EntityObject classes don't implement IBasicEntityInfo interface, but I use T4 to generate:

```
public partial class User : IBasicEntityInfo ,ILastModificationInfo
public partial class Project : IBasicEntityInfo ,ILastModificationInfo
public partial class Group : IBasicEntityInfo ,ILastModificationInfo
public partial class GroupUser : IBasicEntityInfo 
public partial class OperationSystem : IBasicEntityInfo ,ILastModificationInfo
```

T4 is simple:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension="cs" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;

<# 
    String[] classNames = new String[] {"User","Project","Group","GroupUser","OperationSystem","TaskType","Priority","Severity","Status","Version","Platform","Task","TaskUser","Attachment","Comment","Setting"}; 
#>
namespace CamelTrap.Models
{
<# foreach(String className in classNames) { #>
    public partial class <#= className #> : IBasicEntityInfo
    {   
    }
<# } #>
}
```

Making such assumptions solved other problems too and saved me from creating complicated expressions.

Comment: That's useful in many ways (we do almost the same thing), but doesn't actually help solve the problem he's having.

Comment: It does solve the problem, because you can use OrderBy(a => a.ID). My repository knows that every object has ID property by implementing IBasicEntityInfo.

Comment: At the level he's at, he doesn't know the specific type of `E`. So the OrderBy in your comment won't work. Nor can he reliably cast `E` to `IBasicEntityInfo`, unless he has a constraint on `E`, which has its own downsides.